# Generating PNG of map projection from formula

Tags: coordinate-system

I want to build something that takes the formula for a map projection and renders a PNG map.

So the input would be

1. A vector graphic representation of the world that is used to determine how to color every latitude longitude combination.
2. The mathmatical formula for the projection of the form x = f_1(latitude, longitude), y = f_2(latitude, longitude)

And the output would be a PNG of the map, colored appropriately.

I came up with two approaches that might work.

1. Iterate over all the x,y values in the PNG, and use a numerical solver to find the corresponding latitude and longitude. Once we have the latitude and longitude we can use the vector graphic map to determine what ocean/country/etc it is in and then color the pixel appropriately.
2. Iterate over latitude and longitude and trivially use the formulas to find the corresponding x and y values.

The first approach has the problem of solving for the correct latitude and longitude from the x and y values. The second approach has the problem of it not being easy to 'hit' every pixel.

Does anyone know which is the better approach or how it is done normally?

Comment: Convert your lat/long coordinates to a WKT Polygon, use GDAL to convert from WKT to png

Comment: @nmtoken Thanks for the suggestion. Checking it out.